# Divide a path in multiple full paths in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split, path

I try to find the best way to have an array of 'full' paths from one path.

Input :

```
'source/folder/folder2/folder3/file'
```

I would like to have this output:

```
[
'/',
'/folder',
'/folder/folder2',
'/folder/folder2/folder3',
'/folder/folder2/folder3/file'
]
```

Currently, I can see that my code is not optimized:

```
 pathArray = path.split('/');
 if (pathArray [0] === '') {
   pathArray .shift();
 }
 if (pathArray [pathArray .length - 1] === '') {
    pathArray .pop();
 }
 const finalArrayPath = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
   let path = '';
   for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
     path = path + pathArray[j] + '/';
   }
   finalArrayPath.push(path);
 }
```

More of that, my code have a / at the end of each paths and source at the beginning, I could add code for removing these but I would like a more optimized code.

Comment: client side javascript or nodejs?

Comment: this is client side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` method you could do:

```js
const path = "source/folder/folder2/folder3/file";

const result = path.split("/").slice(1).reduce((allPaths, subPath) => {
  const lastPath = allPaths[allPaths.length-1];
  allPaths.push(lastPath.endsWith("/") ? (lastPath + subPath) : `${lastPath}/${subPath}`);
  return allPaths;
}, ["/"]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: really smart way to do that !

Answer (score 0):

With a single for loop...

```js
const path = 'source/folder/folder2/folder3/file';

const [root, ...pathArr] = path.split('/');

const paths = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= pathArr.length; i++) {
  paths.push(`/${pathArr.slice(0, i).join('/')}`);
}

console.log('root: ', root);
console.log('paths: ', paths);
```

Or using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)...

```js
const path = 'source/folder/folder2/folder3/file';

const [root, ...pathArr] = path.split('/');

const paths = Array.from(
  { length: pathArr.length + 1 },
  (_, i) => `/${pathArr.slice(0, i).join('/')}`
);

console.log('root: ', root);
console.log('paths: ', paths);
```